# Show button in a column only for newly added row

Tags: angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I have a ui-Grid where there are 5 columns. Have provided an option to add a new row. The last column is a icon for deleting the row. But i need the delete button to be enabled only for the newly added rows and not for the previously present one. Like if i click on Add row, then the delete button for that row should be enabled, for others it should be disabled. Any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a field to the row entity, let's say `new` and use it to drive the state of the button by adding an `ng-disabled` tag in your custom template.

In your controller:

```
gridOptions.data = myData

[...]

var newRecord = {
  [...]
  new: true
};
myData.push(newRecord);
```

In your template:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="!row.entity.new">Delete</a>
```